# How to "open brackets" in array that consist from arrays with numbers?

Tags: algorithm

I have an array like:

```
[10, [26, [32, [49]]]]
```

It's a bunch of nested 2-element arrays, where the first element is a number, and the second element is the next array. I need to transform it to a single array like:

```
[10, 26, 32, 49]
```

What algorithm do I need to use?

Any language or pseudocode would be nice.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
function format($arr)
{
    if(is_array($arr[1])) {
        format($arr[1]);
    } else {
        // What's next?
    }
}
```

Comment: Traverse it recursively and push all the encountered elements into a new array?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Show us **YOUR** code.

Comment: MrSmith42, I can provide some code what I tried, but I doubt it will help: I have no idea about logic.

ybungalobill, for example? I tried and write this
`function format($arr)
    {
        if(is_array($arr[1]))
        {
            format($arr[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Whats next?
        }
    }`.

Comment: Comments markdown is awful, sorry

Comment: If you search on the phrase "how to flatten an array", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant recursive solution exists for the above problem. 
Consider the following in pseudocode/semi python 
The big list to be processed is called L, the number which is the first element is L[0] and the nested list is L[1]

```
def process(L):
    if(len(L)==1)):  
          return L  // this is the innermost list, the base case, which we return as is it.
    L1=process(L[1]) //we solve the problem for the nested list
    L1.insert(L[0]) //note we must insert at 0 whichever language you're using, so a linked list or a stack might better suit your needs here
    return L1
```